# How we get the result of this limit?

Tags: functions

I met a problem while doing my homework. Let say we have a formula:

> $(a_3 + d)\cdot sin(\theta_2) - b_3 \cdot cos(\theta_2) - a_2 = 0$

Now we knew $a_3$, d(in this case is exactly 0), $b_3$ and $a_2$. How can we get the result of $\theta_2$?

Comment: What limit are you taking? Is `theta2` approaching something?

Comment: Usually there is no simple  expression (= with usual functions) of the solutions

Comment: Yes, `theta2` is within `(-135°,-45°)`